# how sessions and cookies actually managed for different browsers?

Tags: session-cookies

After I logged into an application in a browser and gave the same URL in another browser, it was showing me again to log into that application.

How does the application know whether which browser I am using since both comes under same IP address?

Does it send the sessions and cookies to browser such that other browser cannot access those cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Session and cookies are per browser, not per IP address.